# Google Sheets Divide Results of the Import Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this GoogleSheets,

With a import range query : `=IMPORTRANGE("1Z76YA8","'Sales'!1:1")`

[image]

Is it possible to divide the results of my import range with "row 1 (currency euro) "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("1Z76YA8","'Sales'!1:1")/B1:1)
```

If you do not want to output when row 1 is blank:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B="",,IMPORTRANGE("1Z76YA8","'Sales'!1:1")/B1:1))
```